# Change Git Log Plus/Minus Signs to Anything Custom?

Tags: sql-server, git, t-sql, cmd, git-log

Git CMD line noob here, **how do I change the default plus/minus (+/-) signs to something more unique**, such as (>>>/<<<) or (|/~). Or any other symbol not as common as (+/-)!

Reason: I am trying to automate a report that collects all the changes to our *schema*.sql files. I have the line below that does an adequate job:

```
git log -p --since="14 days ago" -- *Schema*.sql
```

My only real issue with the output is the plus/minus (+/-) signs which are used to show what has been added or removed:

```
+ This line was added
- This line was removed
```

Comments in SQL (t-SQL) are two minus signs (--), so when a comment is removed, I end up with this:

```
--- This comment was removed
```

If I can substitute the (+/-) with a unique value I can format the results and make a nice, pretty report for the people that want to see things like that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--output-indicator-new=<char>
--output-indicator-old=<char>
--output-indicator-context=<char>
```

Specify the character wanted for -old.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_common_diff_options

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---output-indicator-newltchargt

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if git can do this natively, but you can certainly achieve what you want by piping the output of `git log` into `sed`.  For example to change the plus to '$' and the minus to '%' in your report you could use the following command:

```
git log -p --since="14 days ago" -- *Schema*.sql | sed 's/^+/$/g' | sed 's/^-/%/g'
```

Comment: One call: `sed -e 's/^+/$/g' -e 's/^-/%/g'`